# arranging the numbers with duplicate entries deleted

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a[9],i,j,r,t,min,c=0;
for(r=0;r<9;r++)
    scanf("%d",&a[r]);

for (j=0;j<9;j++) {
    min=a[j];
    for(i=j;i<9;i++) {
        if(a[i] <  min ) {
            c=i;
            min=a[i];
        }
    }
t=a[j];
a[j]=min;
a[c]=t;
}

for(r=0;r<9;r++)
    printf("%d",a[r]);
}
```

This is the code which i have to arrange the numbers entered byt the user in ascending order. 
If input is 1 2 3 2 4 1 5 6 3 output is 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 but i want the output to be 1 2 3 4 5 6 i.e. duplicate entries deleted.Please help me.

Comment: First thing you should care about: code indentation

Comment: Then sort, then pick multiple ones in a single pass.

Comment: Hint: If I just printed this number, no need to print it again.

Comment: firstly sort the array then delete the duplicate entries.

Comment: @KhairulBasar , OP already sorted his array. He wants to delete the duplicate values in it.

Comment: you can simply skip printing, when the previous value was the same as the current.

Answer (score 1):

If the range of the numbers is given then you can do it by using a boolean array which will store `1` to the corresponding index of the element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define NUM_RANGE 10

int main(){
    int num;
    bool freq[NUM_RANGE + 1] = {0};
    for(int r = 0; r < 9; r++){
         scanf("%d",&num);
         freq[num] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RANGE + 1; i++)
         if(freq[i])
             printf("%d ", i);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3};
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    int i, j, t;

    for (j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        for(i=j+1;i<n;){
            if(a[i] == a[j]){
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[--n];
                a[n] = t;
                continue;
            }
            if(a[i] < a[j]){
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the procedure you can follow.

1. You sort your array (as you have already done). Your sorting algorithm has O(n^2) worst-case-running time where n is the number of Elements in your array. If you care about running time, the optimal running time which can be achieved is O(n logn) [MergeSort].
2. Next, we need to find the duplicates and delete them. 
   Since you have already ordered them just loop through your array and check that every number a[i] and the next number a[i+1] are different. If they are not, delete it and fill the empty space by moving all the rest of the array one forward.

So:

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){

   if(a[i] == a[i+1]){
      deletNumber(i); //deletes number at position i in the array and shifts the   
                      //rest of the array so the empty space is filled.
   }
}

void deleteNumber(int i){
  int j; 

  for(j = i; j<8; j++){

    a[j] = a[j++];  
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for your statement?

Comment: It has quadratic time complexity (i.e. bad), and invokes an undefined behaviour (i.e. wrong).

Comment: I agree with your first point about the quadratic time complexity but the question did not ask for any particular time complexity. Concerning  the undefined behavior, I do not entirely understand what you mean, but you are welcome to edit my answer and correct the mistake.